# Golden quantum dots blinking and plasmons

Tags: plasmon, quantum-dots

I have been reading [this article](https://www.nature.com/articles/nnano.2014.298) about golden QD as a way to avoid QD blinking. I understand that the surface plasmons here act as a nano antenna which strongly concentrates the light, but I don’t really understand what happens to the emission- especially why do I get only one state when the QD is covered in a golden nano shell? How does the plasmic nano shell help avoiding blinking?

Comment: I guess the first question is:  what causes the blinking?